# openstack modify libvirt xml configuration

Tags: linux, virtual-machine, kvm, openstack

I am experimenting some options and trying to ad following option in `openstack` running instance.

`<driver name='vhost' queues='5' rx_queue_size='512' tx_queue_size='512'/>`

I did following steps and didn't work.

1. virsh edit
2. virsh define
3. shutdown & start instance

Verify using `virsh dumpxml  but i am not seeing my changes there :(

How people modify xml in openstack? (I am using latest libvirtd 3.9.x & openstack version `queens`)

Answer (score 1):

You may try to change VPS state to "error" via OpenStack CLI command. This makes OpenStack to ignore real VPS state in hypervisor. Then you can do the same commands to update xml as you described:

1. virsh edit
2. virsh define
3. shutdown & start instance